# Magento2: How to add custom fields on checkout with multiple addresses -> Select shipping method page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I want to add the custom fields on the select shipping method page (checkout with multiple addresses).

[image]

How to add custom input field on the select shipping method page?. I want to add the input field below the shipping method shown in the above image.

Answer (score 0):

**Configure multiple address shipping in Magento 2**

On the **Admin panel**, click **Store**. In the **Settings** section, select **Configuration**

Select **Multishipping** **Settings** under **Sales** in the panel on the left

Open the **Options** section, and continue with following

[image]

In the Allow Shipping to **Multiple Addresses** field, select **Yes** if you allow

In the **Maximum Qty Allowed for Shipping to Multiple Addresses field**, enter the maximum number of shipping address that you allow

When complete, click **Save Config**.

Comment: Hi, My question is if I select the shipping method that time I have to show the custom input fields. For example, if select shipping method based on the shipping method I have to display the delivery date input field and comment input field, How I can do this in checkout with multiple addresses (select shipping method page)...